# TeamCity url to view report tab of latest build

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

Here is the url to a custom report tab of a specific build:

`http://teamcity/viewLog.html?buildId=1738&buildTypeId=bt16&tab=report_TODO_items`

What I cannot figure out is how to change that URL to always point to the latest build (finished or successful).

There is help on how get artifact data here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts

But `http://teamcity/bt16/.lastSuccessful/viewLog.html&tab=report_TODO_items` doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer on the Overview tab of my build configuration in the "Permalink" section at the bottom:

`http://teamcity/viewLog.html?buildId=lastSuccessful&buildTypeId=bt16&tab=report_TODO_items`

Comment: `buildId=lastFinished` will get the result of the latest build. `lastSuccessful` will only work if the build succeeded